# PHP Warning fopen() permission denied

Tags: php, apache, fopen

I am new to PHP and I have little experience with manipulating files with PHP; I keep getting a 'permission denied' warning message and can't seem to figure out a solution.
I've made a simple web application with one php file that has just these two lines:

```php
$file = fopen( '/Users/<myname>/Desktop/file.txt', 'r' );
var_dump( json_decode( $file ) );
```

to see whether the variable has been set.

When I run the script on chrome, I get:

> **Warning**: fopen(/Users/<myname>/Desktop/file.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in **/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/testwebsite/filereader.php** on line **1**
>
> NULL

Presumably, the **NULL** is because `$file` has not be set or is empty.

I have read numerous posts online and I am still very confused about the explanations given. From my understanding, it is a permissions problem where I have not given the right privileges to some file.

I have tried many command lines such as `chmod 755 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/testwebsite/filereader.php` to give permission to the script to at least be able to read a file but to no avail.

I have also read that it might be due to some user privileges that were not properly set so I've ran these to command to see who the user was:

- ```php
  echo get_current_user();
  ```

  return 'daemon'?, a program that runs in the background?
- ```php
  exec('whoami');
  ```

  returns '<myname>', my current machine's name

I am not sure how to proceed from here, whether to give permission to my machine that runs the script or 'daemon'.

I just want the application to run on at least my personal computer.

Comment: How are you running PHP?  If it is through a webserver or other backend framework, the user ID of the instance is probably not the one you expect.  Therefore *that* user needs to have read permission.

Comment: When you run a script from the webserver, it usually runs as a user like `www-user` or `www-data`. This user doesn't generally have access to ordinary users' files.

Comment: I am running php through XAMPP for OS X 7.2.29 with Apache

Comment: The right access issue is not with the script you run, otherwise it won't run at all, but with the file you try to open: `/Users/<myname>/Desktop/file.txt`. Try chmod'ing this one.

Comment: You server should _absolutely_ not be allowed to just willy-nilly access files in user directories. That's would be an amazing security vulnerability. Instead read/write to a location that is under the server's control.

Comment: I tried ```chmod 777 /Users/<myname>/Desktop/file.txt``` in my terminal and ran the script again which still gave me the same error. Is it not because I am running the script on a localhost?

Comment: @get_php_workin: No. But it can be related to the fact that you are outside of your document root and trying to access a file in your user folder is a really wonky idea, as pointed by comments above.

Comment: If your webserver is setup correctly you cannot access files that are not in or under your DocumentRoot. If you want to you will need to add an Alias to the Apache config

Comment: Well what I am trying to achieve ultimately is read Google Chrome's 'Bookmarks' file that contains all of my bookmarks in a JSON-like format and simply echo every link in it.

Comment: Based on your paths it looks like you are running it on your local system. Just go to your desktop and right click the file. Select properties. See if its read only or what? Just to take that out of the equation.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Ah, making an alias did exactly what I want it it to do. Thank you.